# how make integer data type from post method when data store in session

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my post data

```
$post=$this->input->post('input_slide');
```

Above my `$post` variable is a string data type when I check in `var_dump($post)`. But I want to convert INTEGER data type. So wrote this code

```
$post_int=sprintf("%d",$post);
```

Then I store session `$post_int` variable

```
    //set my session
    $this->session->set_userdata('slide_count',$post_int);  
    //retrive my session
    $i=$this->session->userdata('slide_count');
```

Here my `$i` perform integer behavior in mysql query.

> But My question is why `var_dump($i)` still show STRING data type and how mysql match this.
>   Here my mysql query

```
$sql="

    SELECT  DISTINCT p.insert_operation,DATE(p.dates) AS pur_date 
    FROM product_purchases AS p
    WHERE DATE(p.dates) BETWEEN 
    (
        SELECT  DATE_SUB(date(dates), INTERVAL  ? DAY) FROM product_purchases order by product_purchase_id desc limit 1
    )               
    AND 
    (
        SELECT DATE(dates) FORM product_purchases ORDER BY product_purchase_id DESC LIMIT 1
    )
    GROUP BY pur_date
    order BY pur_date DESC
";
$query=$this->db->query($sql,$i);
```

Note that mysql show error when I don't use `sprintf()`.

Comment: sprintf returns a string... your are probably after [intval](http://php.net/intval)

Comment: What error does MySQL throw? Because `INTERVAL '1' DAY` and `INTERVAL 1 DAY` works. You are probably posting something other that integer, that's why it doesn't work without `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 2):

[`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprinft) always [returns](https://eval.in/54145) a string produced according to the formatting string format.

Remove the `sprintf()` statement and cast your variable as an `int`:

```
$i = (int) $this->session->userdata('slide_count');
```

Or, use [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval):

```
$i = intval( $this->session->userdata('slide_count') );
```

Comment: Thanks. But my second question was why do mysql support this string?

Comment: @imran: See Glavić's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330996/how-make-integer-data-type-from-post-method-when-data-store-in-session/19331022#comment28641868_19330996) above.